# Allow camunda task completion by only candidate users/groups

Tags: camunda, bpmn, camunda-modeler

I have a Spring boot software that integrates with the Camunda. I am trying to manage the Camunda tasks/execution from the spring boot app, but I am unable to block any user from completing a task via the taskService.

In other words, let's take an example of "Leave request" process.
1- the employee starts a process
2- manager validates the requests >> candidate user = manager
3- send notification to employee

In order to handle the process execution from Spring boot, I us the camunda task service:

```
        ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
        TaskService taskService = processEngine.getTaskService();
        Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(processInstanceId).singleResult();
        taskService.complete(task.getId(), taskVariables);
```

The thing is that any user can call the taskService.complete(task.getId(), taskVariables) and he will be able to complete the task.

How can I ensure that camunda does not let the user "Employee1" validate the request?

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Boot starter does not enable authorization by default. You can enable authorizations using:

```
camunda:
  bpm:
    authorization:
      enabled: true
```

Please see: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/user-guide/process-engine/authorization-service/

to understand authorization concept and how to configure authorizations for different resources.